# What are the destructive commands in git?

Tags: git

I read that Git mainly adds information about the repository's history, trying to remember every change made, but that there are also commands that make irreversible changes.

What are the commands that I should really pay attention to and avoid using wrongly because there is no turning back?

Comment: When you answer the question below, please remember to explain what the command does!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two kinds of "destructive" here -- commands that are destructive to your git history and commands that discard changes in your working copy.

Commands that discard *work tree changes*:

1. `git reset`
2. `git checkout`

As others have mentioned, the combination of the reflog and the fact that git objects don't immediately get discarded (unless you turn on automatic cleanup) means that you can usually undo operations like `git reset/rebase/merge`.

These commands, though, actually *discard git objects*, eliminating the ability to undo:

1. `git gc` (by default, this prunes unreachable objects that are at least 2 weeks old)

Comment: In my opinion, the most destructive git commands that ones that discard the working tree changes. It should be always safe to "do a backup" with 'git stash; git stash pop'. You can later (up to your gc prune limit) recover "lost" versions via command such as: gitk --all -n 5000 --all $(git fsck | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}'; git log -g --pretty='format:%H') [this will open gitk frontend with up to 5000 commits including all "lost" commits].

Answer (score 7):

According to [http://blog.reverberate.org/2009/07/30/gits-needs-a-new-interface/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120117072136/http://blog.reverberate.org/2009/07/30/gits-needs-a-new-interface/)

```
 $ git checkout foo.c
```

... will overwrite any local modifications you may have to foo.c without asking.

Comment: Quite true - it's even more destructive than I thought. I just did a `git checkout 6bb33a8 .` hoping to get the one file that changed in that commit, but it also wiped out my staged changes to other files, replacing them with the contents in that commit.  I thought it might stick something in the reflog to protect me, but no such luck.

Answer (score 3):

git reset --hard cannot be undone

Answer (score 3):

You can lose uncommitted changes by using the `git reset` command.  If your changes are committed, you are protected by the reflog for a number of days before it gets cleaned up by `gc`.

For example, if you `checkout`, `rebase`, `reset`, or `merge` which all introduce changes, you can go back to a previous commit by running the `reflog` command and using `reset` to reset your HEAD to an old commit.